# The type is not registered as safe "Custom Actions"

Tags: 2007, development, wspbuilder, custom-action

I am trying to create a custom actions using wsp builder, My folder structure is something like this,

[image]

Now when I try to deploy solution nothing comes up however I get this error in my ULS log,

> Failed to create a control from assembly '', class '': The control
>   with assembly name '', ' class name '' is not allowed for web at URL
>   ''. The type is not registered as safe.

I removed assembly names myself, however I read this [another question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11524/the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe-when-trying-to-add-a-web-part-installed-by) they asking to add **manifest.xml** file but not sure where it will go and whether creating a wsp using wsp builder will include manifest.xml in wsp and will solve the problem ?

Comment: manifest.xml is created on the fly by wspbuilder when you build the wsp, so even if you add it to the project it will be removed as its used then deleted by wspbuilder! The type is not registered as safe means you need to add code that will register it as safe in the web.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an empty **Module** to your project, open **properties** window and set **Safe Control Entities** property of a new added module. This property allows to add collection of safe controls.

Comment: thanks but isn't what you suggested works for SharePoint 2010 solutions only ?

Comment: sorry, I missed your tag "2007". Yes the module is a feature of a project tamplate for Sharepoint 2010. I don't remember how this issue can be resolved in SharePoint 2010... But it looks like [this post](http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/archive/2008/05/23/sharepoint-register-an-assembly-as-a-safe-control-in-the-web-config-file.aspx) can be helpful.

Comment: making changes to web config manually isn't recommended neither comes in best practices tho :)

Comment: that why the "Deploy the assembly using a solution package" is the best choise. Because in this approach config modifications are made by SharePoint deployment script.

Comment: ahh I see but thats what happening here, I got a wsp built by wsp builder and deployed using wsp builder as well

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this to the featureActivated function for feature recivers

```
        SPWebConfigModification safeControl = new SPWebConfigModification();
                    safeControl.Path = "configuration/SharePoint/SafeControls";
                    safeControl.Owner = ModuleNameGoesHere;
                    safeControl.Name = "SafeControl[@Assembly='assembly.Name.goes.Here, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b3480442bff091'][@Namespace=Namespace.Name.goes.Here'][@TypeName='*'][@Safe='True']";
                    safeControl.Type = SPWebConfigModification.SPWebConfigModificationType.EnsureChildNode;
                    safeControl.Sequence = 0;
                    safeControl.Value = "<SafeControl Assembly='assembly.Name.goes.Here, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=87b3480442bff091' Namespace=Namespace.Name.goes.Here' TypeName='*' Safe='True' />";
                    mService.WebConfigModifications.Add(safeControl);
                    mService.Update();
                    mService.ApplyWebConfigModifications();
```

the code above adds the the feature or whatever it maybe to the safe controls in web.config for you! this is the recommended way and abides by best practices. So when you activate the feature it will add the safe controls :)

**EDIT**

more can be found here similar to the example above! and yes this is best practice and was put inplace by microsoft specificaly for registering safecontrols without you manually doing it and it automatically gets added every time you activate the feature on the required web.config thats within the webapplication so no need to do it manualy multiple times :) :

> A collection of web.config modifications is a set of commands that,
>   when processed by the web.config manipulator in Microsoft SharePoint
>   Foundation, change the state of the web.config file. You can string
>   together a set of these commands to ensure that they apply the desired
>   tags and attributes within web.config. Each modification is expressed
>   as an object in the administrative object model.
>
> Use the WebConfigModifications property of the SPWebApplication or
>   SPWebService class to get the collection of web.config modifications
>   either in the Web application or in all Web applications within the
>   Web service. To apply modifications that you define through the
>   SPWebConfigModification class to the web.config files in the server
>   farm, call the ApplyWebConfigModifications method on the current
>   content Web service object, as follows:
>   SPWebService.ContentService.ApplyWebConfigModifications

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx

hope it helps :)

**EDIT 2**

If its a webpart then yes you should have a manifest file called manifest.xml with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" SolutionId="{C1938CC9-A1A3-4e20-932C-33ECB2C47481}">
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" Location="WebPartsname.dll">
      <SafeControls>
        <SafeControl Assembly="namespacegoeshere, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=918d2ffdab83e9e8"
                     Namespace="namespacegoeshere" TypeName="*" Safe="True"/>
      </SafeControls>
    </Assembly>
  </Assemblies>
</Solution>
```

hope it sheds some light :)

Comment: yes but its not best practice is it

Comment: ? ofcorse it is, its parts of SPWebConfigModification class which is a part of Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration namespace. Microsoft added it in specifically for that reason! :) check this out if you will: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebconfigmodification.aspx

Comment: oh sorry I thought you were asking to make modifications manually, but I already added above code in my app.config but its not working

Comment: you shouldnt put the above code in the app.config but rather in the feature activated in wspbuilder. check this out :) http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2009/05/10/feature-receiver-basics/

Comment: why not in app.config, I saw one of my workmate doing it, whats wrong with it

Comment: if you want to activate or ammend on different servers or multiple webapplication then you are going to have multiple web.configs. adding to web.config means you will need to do it repetatively over and over again and can lead to human error. This method you only need to do it once and sharepoint will know what web.config it needs to add the code to! Its far safer and easier as you only need to do it once!

Comment: iv ammended my answer slightly if your talking about webparts then yes you need a manifest otherwise it would be as i stated :)