# Custom Action Safe Control 2007

Tags: 2007, development, custom, custom-actions

In extension to [this question of mine](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50785/the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe-custom-actions), If I put location of custom action as

`"Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"`

it gives me error

> Failed to create a control from assembly '', class '': The control
>   with assembly name '', ' class name '' is not allowed for web at URL
>   ''. The type is not registered as safe.

however it works for most I tried in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb802730.aspx)

**Edit**

```
Elements.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Control
  ControlAssembly="abc3333.myworkspacename, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d702315f0f3475cf"
  ControlClass="abc3333.myworkspacename.FeatureFolderName.ClassName"
  Sequence="1"
  Id="AdditionalPageHead"/>

  <CustomAction
      Id="CustomActionName"
      Title="My Custom Action 2"
      Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu"
      RegistrationId="101"
      RegistrationType="List"
      GroupId="ActionsMenu"
      ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/abc.gif"
      ShowInLists="TRUE"
      Sequence="1000"
      ControlAssembly="abc3333.myworkspacename, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,                        PublicKeyToken=d702315f0f3475cf"
      ControlClass="abc3333.myworkspacename.FeatureFolderName.ClassName">
  </CustomAction>

</Elements>
```

Now If I remove ControlAssembly or ControlClass from CustomActions then it stops giving me error and shows my new action in action menu but then I won't be able to do any action, now if I change location and groupId and keep assembly in it then it does work as well.

So I guess GroupID "ActionsMenu" doesn't take control assembly as safe control or something, I think I am missing some concept.

Comment: what Custom Action Group ID did you put in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My User control class wasn't declared as public, so WSP Builder wasn't adding it as a safe control to web.config neither in Manifest.xml.

Many thanks to comments in this [Article by Terry R Not sure who that is personally but solved my issue :).](http://www.michaelbowersox.com/2009/07/23/executing-code-in-assemblies-with-sharepoint-customactions/)