# Problem inserting web part - is not registered as safe

Tags: 2013, web-part, web-config, safe-controls

> A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or
>   imported. The type could not be found or it is not registered as safe.

I've looked at my web.config and I can see the entry seems to be correct

```
 <SafeControl Assembly="XXXXXX.Publishing, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8717c222138003ef" Namespace="XXXXXX.Publishing.WebParts.Buttons" TypeName="*" Safe="True" />
```

Everything works well on my dev environment but not in production. What do I miss?

Comment: Make sure you have a Strong Name Key (.snk) file in the file. That will be used to sign your assemblies.

Comment: check this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11524/the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe-when-trying-to-add-a-web-part-installed-by or also http://roykimsharepoint.wordpress.com/2013/04/27/classic-web-part-errors/

Answer (score 1):

looking at the web.config is not enough!

check to make sure your dll is in GAC and that the assembly is correct.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\
```

make sure your version and public key token are correct! you can check up against your dev enviroment, compare the two safecontrols.