# Error : Type is not registered as safe

Tags: 2010, assembly-references, codebehind

I am creating a code behind file for the site page of sharepoint.
The following page directive was used

```
    <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> 
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="MyCustPage.cs" Inherits="CustPage.MyCustPage, CustPage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44ba9bb23d3f44ca" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"       %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

My .cs file is as follows

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace CustPage
{
    public class MyCustPage:Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('it worked')</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error :

> The base type 'CustPage.MyCustPage' is not allowed for this page. The
>   type is not registered as safe.

I have only done two things : first create an aspx file and then a separate class library.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you change namespace afterwards? Many times Namespace does not get updated. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11524/the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe-when-trying-to-add-a-web-part-installed-by

Comment: I changed the inherits property and added code behind property to the existing wiki page

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your assembly as safe to the SharePoint. If can set this property manually or do it with Visual Studio. Here is some references:

1. ["The type is not registered as safe" when trying to add a web part installed by a WSP](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11524/the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe-when-trying-to-add-a-web-part-installed-by)
2. http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2010/08/20/adding-safe-controls-entries-in-visual-studio-2010/
3. http://blogit.create.pt/andrevala/2010/08/22/adding-an-assembly-to-safe-controls-in-sharepoint-tools-for-visual-studio-2010/
4. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805045.aspx

Keep in mind that you have to sign your assembly with SNK key to add it to Global Assembly Cache

Comment: How do I register the assembly as safe? I have already added the assembly in gac.

Comment: @ABeginner any update on your issue? ECM4D gave you some good indications. As a good habit, you should report back your findings and, most of all, mark the answer as helpful and/or accepted

Comment: @MdMazzotti I am still working on it

Comment: In your project add new empty element (or use existing one if it is), open properties of this element and you can see Safe Control property where you can specify you assembly as safe control. Please follow instructions on http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2010/08/20/adding-safe-controls-entries-in-visual-studio-2010/ . Is is exactly what you need.