# SharePoint 2010 - A Web Part or Web Form Control on this Page cannot be displayed or imported. The type is not registered as safe

Tags: web-part, user-profile, site-collection, user-profile-service, my-site

I have been stuck on this error and am unable to solve it since the past few days. I have googled all I could, but none of the solutions seem to work for me. I'll go through all the steps I've done and hopefully, someone might be able to catch a mistake. Also, I've been developing with SharePoint for quite a while now, but still a beginner in some parts.

I have created my site in my SharePoint and created a new Site Collection for it.
I deployed my web part with the following command in powershell:

```
Update-SPSolution -Identity xxxxx.wsp -GACDeployment -LiteralPath "C:\Users\username\Desktop\xxxxx.wsp"
```

I then go to my created *my site* and add the web part. Which alerts me with the following message.

I tried many solutions including,

1. I checked if my Web part is declared as Safe in the web.config or my root site. It looks like this:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="xxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4a87d6fcb45f5672" Namespace="xxxxx.xxx" TypeName="*" Safe="True" SafeAgainstScript="False" />
```

2. My class name SharePointProject1.WebPartName is declared as public.
3. I've deployed the web part to the GAC by using -GACDeployment
4. The namespace name is same as it is defined in my project.

I also checked my Application Logs in the Event Viewer, but there are no errors mentioned there as well.

After all this, I have a feeling maybe it might be a problem with my User Profile Service creation, though I'm not very familiar with this side of SharePoint.

I followed these two tutorials to create a User Profile Service & the My Site:
http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-the-user-profile-service-in-sharepoint-2010/
http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-create-configure-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2010/

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11524/the-type-is-not-registered-as-safe-when-trying-to-add-a-web-part-installed-by

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP Yes, I've already done it. The safecontrol is already defined in the manifest. The thing is that the Webpart is working fine on my root site. But showing the _not registered as safe_ error on my custom created _my site_.

Comment: I have temporarily fixed the issue by manually writing the safecontrol statement in _my site_'s web.config. But I believe that it should be automatically added there, shouldn't it?